# Creating a movie from images using ffmpeg but getting only one frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, frame, image-conversion

I read 
[How to create an uncompressed AVI from a series of 1000's of PNG images using FFMPEG](https://superuser.com/questions/347433/how-to-create-an-uncompressed-avi-from-a-series-of-1000s-of-png-images-using-ff/347434#347434?newreg=04c50a0e0fde4a069efd8683cd38d3a2) (specifically the section "Compressed RGB, But Also Lossless") and used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i *.png -vcodec qtrle -pix_fmt rgb24 output.mov
```

but the result is a one-frame video... and I have 74 PNGs in my working directory.

I also tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input-%05d.png -vcodec qtrle -pix_fmt rgb24 output.mov
```

following the example from the link, but this doesn't produce anything.

How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried using mencoder instead ?

Comment: The second command should work.  Are your files named `input-00001.png`, `input-00002.png`, etc.?  What does the output from ffmpeg say?

Comment: Please show the complete ffmpeg console output for each command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Do you have a snippet/macro for this line? :)

Comment: @Rajib No, but I should...